# While fetching Data through core data, automatically inserting the existing rows again

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I am new to core data. I am trying to implement it in the object oriented way. As a sample project, I created a View Controller which shows data from an sqlite database through core data and the data is entered by another viewController. 
However, I wanted to handle the data fetching and inserting through a model class, "ContextHandler" and I created another model class "Device" which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

However, when fetching data, I am re-entering the previously entered data.

Here is my storyboards-
[image]

My entity model class is named "Device".

Device.h -

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Device : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *company;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *version;

@end
```

and Device.m -

```
#import "Device.h"

@implementation Device

@dynamic name;
@dynamic company;
@dynamic version;

@end
```

Through the following class, I am inserting and fetching the device object.

The insertion method is

```
-(void)addDeviceWithName:(NSString*)name andCompany:(NSString*)company andVersion:(NSString*)version{

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

    Device *newDevice = [[Device alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    newDevice.name = name;
    newDevice.company = company;
    newDevice.version = version;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if(![self.context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Could not add due to %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

and the fetching method is -

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getDeviceListFromDatabase{
     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    NSMutableArray *devices = [[self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    NSMutableArray *deviceList =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[devices count]];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

    for(NSManagedObject *currentDevice in devices){
       //here I am inserting the data again
        Device *deviceObject = [[Device alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.context];

        deviceObject.name = [currentDevice valueForKey:@"name"];
        deviceObject.company = [currentDevice valueForKey:@"company"];
        deviceObject.version = [currentDevice valueForKey:@"version"];

        [deviceList addObject:deviceObject];
    }
    return deviceList;
}
```

The thing is while I initialise the device object, I end up adding the object to database again.

How to solve this issue. How to initialise the Device class without inserting the data again.

I could not do -

```
Device *deviceObject = [[Device alloc] init];
```

If I do that, the app crashes.
Can anyone please help me out here.

Comment: Do you just want to edit a device object instead of creating a new? Do I get your question right?

Comment: No, I just want to get the objects as Device object to show in my Table. When I fetch, I get NSManagedObject, not Device type object. So, I want to get the object in Device type. No editing required.

Comment: If you have specified `Device` as the class for the `Device` entity in the data model editor, then the fetch will return an array of `Device` objects.  You should just be able to use, for example, `Device *firstDevice = devices[0];`.  Hence no need for your loop to build `Device` objects from `NSManagedObjects`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this bit

```
//here I am inserting the data again
Device *deviceObject = [[Device alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.context];
```

because that really **is** inserting new objects into the Managed Object Context

Your data will be returned in the array of deviceList as `Device`

Comment: No it returns NSManagedObject

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```
-(NSArray *)getDeviceListFromDatabase {
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    // Error handling.
    return array; // This is your array of Device objects
}
```

The fetch returns objects of your type `Device` when you specified this in your model.

Note that the return type is a normal array an not a `NSMutableArray`.